# Вывод из БД GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

Надо вывести из БД статьи от разных авторов, причем чтобы авторы не повторялись и выводилась последняя статья от данного автора. Делаю запрос

```
SELECT write_id, author_id ,name_author, write_date, write, mini_img FROM writes WHERE author_id = '$UserId' GROUP BY author_id
```

он выводит всё без повторов, но запись автора выводится самая первая, как вывести последнюю?

Comment: Выводится без повторов, потому что автор определен по айди, если надо всех авторов с их последней записью - надо начать запрос типа SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если дата у вас с временем хранится, то можно так:

```
SELECT wr.author_id ,wr.name_author, wr.write_date, wr.write, wr.mini_img
FROM writes wr JOIN 
  (SELECT author_id, max(write_date) AS write_date
   FROM writes
   GROUP BY author_id) w ON
   wr.author_id = w.author_id AND wr.write_date = w.wdate;
```

Если только дата и будут несколько записей за одно число, то выведутся лишние.

Comment: спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT write_id, author_id ,name_author, write_date, write, mini_img FROM writes WHERE author_id = '$UserId' AND MAX(write_date) GROUP BY author_id
```

наверно, можно и так

Comment: Не получается, пробовал начинать с SELECT DISTINCT, то же самое

Comment: write_date - это последняя дата публикации?

Comment: это просто дата публикации статьи, ну соответственно, если есть две статьи, первая допустим от 1 января, вторая от 3 января, выводить нужно вторую, а выводит первую

Comment: Запрос

    SELECT write_id, author_id ,name_author, MAX(write_date), write, mini_img FROM writes WHERE author_id = '$UserId'GROUP BY author_id

Comment: Что-то я уже подзабыл sql-ку =) вроде бы, GROUP BY - в запросе лишний, потому что и там в селекте будет только 1 автор. может такой подойдет 

    SELECT DISTINCT write_id, author_id, name_author, MAX(write_date), write, mini_img FROM writes WHERE author_id = '$UserId'

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, если использовать просто DISTINCT без GROUP BY, он выведет только одного автора с максимальной датой... странно, неужели GROUP BY работает только в одном направлении, выводит только первые записи в БД

Answer (score 0):

А почему не попробуете через `ORDER BY desc write_date`?

Comment: выведутся все записи, только отсортированные по дате, включая повторы, если совместно использовать GROUP BY author_id ORDER BY write_date DESC то результат будет такой же, что и без использования ORDER BY

Comment: Запрос 

    SELECT write_id, author_id, name_author, write_date, write, mini_img, max(write_date) as "wdate" 
    FROM writes WHERE author_id = '$UserId' GROUP BY author_id having write_date=wdate